# Derivative with respect to a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Consider the following;

$$
J = L^{\text{T}}KR
$$

where

$$
L \in \mathbb{R}^{p}, ~~ K \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m}, ~~ r \in \mathbb{R}^{m}
$$

I am attempting to find $ \frac{dJ}{dK}$. This is what I have done so far;

\begin{align}
J &= \begin{bmatrix}
       \ell_1 & \ell_2 & \dotsm & \ell_p
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
       k_{1,1} & k_{1,2} & \dotsm & k_{1,m}  \\
       k_{2,1} & k_{2,2} & \dotsm & k_{2,m}  \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
       k_{p,1} & k_{p,2} & \dotsm & k_{p,m}  
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
       r_1 \\ 
       r_2 \\
       \vdots \\
       r_m
    \end{bmatrix} \\[0.5em]
&= \ell_1 (k_{1,1}r_1 + k_{1,2}r_2 + \cdots + k_{1,m}r_m) + \\
&~~~~~ \ell_2 (k_{2,1}r_1 + k_{2,2}r_2 + \cdots + k_{2,m}r_m)+ \\
&~~~~~ \cdots + \\
&~~~~~ \ell_p (k_{p,1}r_1 + k_{p,2}r_2 + \cdots + k_{p,m}r_m)
\end{align}

and so,
\begin{align}
 \frac{dJ}{dK}
&= \ell_1 (r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_m) + \\
&~~~~~ \ell_2 (r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_m)+ \\
&~~~~~ \cdots + \\
&~~~~~ \ell_p (r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_m) \\ \\[0.5em]
&= L^{\text{T}} [1]_{p \times m} R
\end{align}

where $ [1]_{p \times m} $ is a $p \times m$ matrix of all ones.

My question is this: 1) did I do this properly, and 2) is there a more elegant way to express the solution?

Comment: The gradient should work out to $\,LR^T.\;$ Your initial expansion is correct, but then you  jump to an incorrect conclusion. As an intermediate step, try calculating the derivative with respect to a single component $K_{ij}\;$